# OpenCV Select Ink On Scanned Page

Tags: python, opencv, mask, threshold

Say we have a picture of a page with text on it. However, a threshold is not sufficient. On an example image, the page has a large shadow that covers half the image, such that at some points, there is paper that is darker than the lightest ink.

What's the best way to get a mask of the ink on the page? I'm thinking it's something like edge detection, although I wouldn't then know how to select the inner part of the ink.

I'm doing this in Python, so answers in that would be most helpful!

Comment: did u try filtering the image with the color of ink say (0,0,255)

Comment: Yep. In the question, I said that the darkest parts of the paper can appear darker than the lightest parts of the ink, so this is no-go.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try:

- Convert the image to HSV and check the hue component
- Use algorithms to remove shadow from the image and then process it.
  An example of such methods can be found  in [this paper](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/~venky/SE263/papers/Salvador_CVIU2004.pdf)